# Multiple Django site with Apache mod_wsgi second site always crash

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, pywin32

I am using Python2.7, pywin32-216.win32-py2.7.exe, and mod_wsgi3.3 in Apache2.2

```
Listen 8080
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 "C:/www/site1/site1app.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/www/site1">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /site2 "C:/www/site2/site2app.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/www/site2">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Everytime restarting Apache the first site works fine and the second site crash and throw

```
AssertionError at /
No exception supplied
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py in            __import_pywin32_system_module__, line 114
```

I understand from http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/92764d08a8e7697e and [Multiple django sites on Apache / Windows / mod_wsgi - problem with win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969669/multiple-django-sites-on-apache-windows-mod-wsgi-problem-with-win32) that I can use pywin32#212 or pywin32#210, however it means I have to use Python2.6 instead and I need to use Python2.7.

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: By “the first site”, do you mean “site1” or “whichever comes earlier in the Apache config”?

Comment: The first site means the first site I try to load from browser, it always works but not the next one