# Running two Django Apps on Apache with mod_auth_sspi and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, single-sign-on, sspi

I've been running one Django app with Single Sign-On enabled by mod_auth_sspi using mod_wsgi.

Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 mod_auth_sspi/1.0.4

Problem is, that I can't add second Django app, which uses the same modules, because I want to use Single Sign-On too. If I add second app, Apache authenticates only the first requested app. The second one throws Error 500 - Internal server error. If I restart Apache and try to request second app at first, it works. But then when I request the first app, it throws error 500 (same error as the first).

error.log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=4724): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/www/app2/app2.wsgi'.
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 169, in get_response
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 151, in get_traceback_html
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return t.render(c)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\base.py", line 123, in render
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return self._render(context)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\base.py", line 117, in _render
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\base.py", line 744, in render
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\debug.py", line 73, in render_node
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     result = node.render(context)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\debug.py", line 90, in render
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\base.py", line 536, in resolve
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\template\\defaultfilters.py", line 695, in date
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return format(value, arg)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 285, in format
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return df.format(format_string)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 191, in r
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 30, in format
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     s = unicode(s)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\functional.py", line 206, in __unicode_cast
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\translation\\__init__.py", line 81, in ugettext
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 286, in ugettext
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 276, in do_translate
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\translation\\trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     app = import_module(appname)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     __import__(name)
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\contrib\\admin\\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\contrib\\admin\\helpers.py", line 3, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\contrib\\admin\\util.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     from django.db import models
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\db\\models\\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     from django.db.models.fields.files import FileField, ImageField
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\db\\models\\fields\\files.py", line 9, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\files\\storage.py", line 9, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     from django.core.files import locks, File
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\files\\locks.py", line 25, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     import pywintypes
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib\\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]   File "C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib\\pywintypes.py", line 114, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121]     assert sys.modules[modname] is old_mod
[Tue Feb 28 09:57:48 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.121] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught AssertionError while rendering:
```

conf/wsgi.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app1 "C:/www/app1/app1.wsgi"

<Directory "C:/www/app1">
  Allow from all
#  AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<Location /app1>
  AuthName "server"
  AuthType SSPI
  SSPIAuth On
  SSPIAuthoritative On
  SSPIUsernameCase lower
#  SSPIDomain DOMAIN
  require valid-user
</Location>

WSGIScriptAlias /app2 "C:/www/app2/app2.wsgi"

<Directory "C:/www/app2">
  Allow from all
#  AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<Location /app2>
  AuthName "server"
  AuthType SSPI
  SSPIAuth On
  SSPIAuthoritative On
  SSPIUsernameCase lower
#  SSPIDomain DOMAIN
  require valid-user
</Location>

Alias /static/ "c:/static-root/"
<Directory "c:/static-root/">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

c:/www/app2/app2.wsgi (app1.wsgi is similar):

```
import os
import sys

path = 'c:/www/'
apps_path = 'c:/www/app2/'
if path not in sys.path:
  sys.path.append(path)
if apps_path not in sys.path:
  sys.path.append(apps_path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app2.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Do you know what to do to get both apps work with Single Sign-On? I don't know, if it is Django's fault, mod_wsgi fault or mod_auth_sspi fault. Can you help me, please?

EDIT:
It looks, that it doesn't depend on mod_auth_sspi module.

Answer (score 2):

It seem to be a pywin32 error, answered here:
[Multiple django sites on Apache / Windows / mod_wsgi - problem with win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969669/multiple-django-sites-on-apache-windows-mod-wsgi-problem-with-win32)

There is some python version check, which does something with modules and raises:

```
AssertionError: assert sys.modules[modname] is old_mod
```

Bug is reported, but not resolved:

https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2905909&group_id=78018&atid=551954

https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3496224&group_id=78018&atid=551954

Temporary solution is comment out two lines in *win32/lib/pywintypes.py*:

```
if sys.version_info < (3,0):
    #next two lines are problematic!!!!!
    #assert sys.modules[modname] is old_mod 
    #assert mod is old_mod
    pass
else:
    assert sys.modules[modname] is not old_mod
    assert sys.modules[modname] is mod
    # as above - re-reset to the *old* module object then update globs.
    sys.modules[modname] = old_mod
    globs.update(mod.__dict__)
```