# Xlwings error in using python modules

Tags: python, module, pywin32, xlwings

I'm attempting to use Xlwings for Python, however having installed Python 3.5, pywin32 extensions and Xlwings I get the following error when starting import:

```
from xlwings import workbook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from xlwings import workbook
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _xlwindows as xlplatform
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 117, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    assert sys.modules[modname] is not old_mod
AssertionError
```

Comment: The issue is with `pywin32`, see my comment with Bob's answer. On Mac, xlwings runs easily with Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try commenting out the asserts (replace them with a `pass`) and see if it works. Otherwise you're going to need to debug pywintypes.</strike>

[Felix Zumstein just informed me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051827/xlwings-error-in-using-python-modules/32052097#comment52008742_32052097) that the above suggestion won't work:

> When you comment out those lines, then it fails further down when doing `from pywintypes import TimeType: ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeType'`

However, [downgrading may solve this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951877/5221082)

Comment: When you comment out those lines, then it fails further down when doing `from pywintypes import TimeType`: `ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeType'`

Comment: @FelixZumstein well then that's a no-go, but downgrading should hopefully work. pywin32 has (known) issues.

Comment: thing is that there's really just one version (219) available for Python 3.5 in binary format ,-)

Comment: @FelixZumstein why haven't you answered this question yet? :P I'll gladly delete my answer

Comment: Well, I haven't found a working solution yet, I was just trying out your suggestions ;-)

Comment: @FelixZumstein ahh ok. I figured since you wrote the thing, you'd know best

Comment: I wish I had more rep to comment on the question. I want to ask if the user installed pywin32 from pip

Comment: Thanks for your reponses ive found by downgrading to python 3.3 it all works

Comment: Hello. Have things moved since last summer when the OP asked his question?  I have Python 3.5 installed, and I am not willing to downgrade. Still, xlwings doesn't work. Ah!

Answer (score 0):

After Much trial and error ive found that downgrading to Python 3.3 works

Thnak you for all the responses

Comment: Using the Anaconda distribution now gives you an easy way to use xlwings with Python 3.5